# Windows Scheduled Task Arguments with spaces

Tags: windows, cmd, scheduled-tasks, command-line-arguments

I've looked at several threads that appear to have the same issue as I am, but I don't see a solution that will work for me.

Windows 7 OS

I have a simple .bat file. I have a scheduled task to run that .bat file. No issues there.

I'm trying to add an argument to direct the output to a text file. I add the > character followed by my file path into the "Add Arguments (optional)" text box in the Scheduled Task. For example:

```
>D:\Output Files\file.txt 2>&1
```

When the task runs, the file is created, but the only text within is the following:

```
'""D:\Output' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've tried single quotes, double quotes, double double quotes, and triple double quotes, and nothing I try seems to work. What am I doing wrong and what do I need to add/subtract to get the .bat output written into the file.

For some reason editing the .bat and surrounding my entire code in ()'s and putting >D:\Output Files\file.txt 2>&1 after the closing parenthesis didn't work for me either, but I'm not sure why.

The file paths above are examples, but the real path I'm using has a space, and I can't control that... otherwise I'd just remove the space from the folder name.

Any help at all is immensely appreciated.

Comment: Try `D:\Output^ Files\file.txt`

Comment: Or possibly you can use the 8.3 short name, although that may be disabled: `D:\OUTPUT~1\file.txt` - use `dir /x` to find out what it is.

Comment: You are my savior! I'm at a loss as to why that wasn't easier to find in my Googling, but hopefully the title and tags of this make it easier for others who've had or will have the same issue. Thank you @Blorgbeard... thank you thank you thank you! :)

Comment: @Night1505 - Which one worked? Or, did both work?

Comment: Oh, sorry... it was his first suggestion that worked right off the bat! I didn't have to even try the second way. :)

Comment: Relying on the Task Scheduler to rewrite the command line for you may not handle quoted arguments correctly, depending on the Windows version (it works in Windows 10). Instead you can explicitly run `cmd.exe`, and use the arguments `/c ""path\to\script.bat" >"D:\Output Files\file.txt" 2>&1"`.